# Simple tool to test Amazon EC2 instance throughput?

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-testing, bandwidth-measuring

I'm looking for a way to test the <strike>bandwidth</strike> throughput of a c3.8xlarge instance.

I have two c3.8xlarge instances set up, so I imagine I could use the other to simulate the traffic.

What's the easiest way to go about it?

Comment: iperf is simple enough, and very useful. keep in mind that you will probably not get correct values if you test between two aws instances

Comment: @dusan.bajic Why would he not get accurate data testing between two EC2 instances?

Comment: @EEAA, It may be because the numbers reported by iperf when testing between EC2 instances, which could even be located in the same region and zone, would be unrealistic high when compared to testing the c3.8xlarge instance with servers outside the EC2 network.

Comment: I think we need more details.  Are you looking for the throughput from the instance to an outside source or strictly between two instances?

Comment: As a reference I would like to first know the throughput between the two c3.8xlarge instances. Then I want to test from an outside source. I have just performed the iperf test between the two instances, and it gives me readings at 1.72 Gbits/sec to 1.73 Gbits/sec Gbps. Why so low? Both instances have 10 GbE interfaces so I would expect much closer to 8-9 Gbps.

Comment: Are the two instances in a VPC?

Comment: @EEAA, I haven't set up VPC, so I believe not.

Comment: Are they in the same region and availability zone?

Comment: If you need full bandwidth between nodes, you'll need to use [placement groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html).

Comment: @Nathan C - Yes, they are in the same region and availability zone. I will have to read about placement groups, do you think it is needed to see speeds over 1.7 Gbps?

Comment: /etc/sysctl.conf/limits.d/90-nproc.conf (which overrides values in /etc/security/limits.conf) has "* soft nproc 1024". Should setting this number higher or even to unlimited do anything with regards to eliminating this 1.73 Gbps limit?

Comment: If you test from another EC2 instance, you'll only be testing the in-datacenter bandwidth. Even if your 2nd server is in a different EC2 regions - you will be testing over Amazon-optimized infrastructure. So if you want to see how much bandwidth you have for serving end users across the internet, you need to be sure your test measures traffic in the same way.

Comment: Thank you @CMerrill, first I'm trying to find out if there are limitations on the instance that makes it impossible to archive speeds over 1.73 Gbits/sec. When I find out what to change in order to take full advantage of the 10 GbE adapter on the c3.8xlarge instance. Then when I figure that out I will test from outside the Amazon environment.

Comment: More about the 1.73 Gbps cap here: http://serverfault.com/questions/570879/1-73-gbps-at-best-on-an-amazon-ec2-10-gigabit-instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

few options..

- (nu)ttcp
- netcat and dd
- iperf as someone already mentioned

ttcp is pretty simple.  on one machine do `nuttcp -S` and on the other do `nuttcp -v -v -i10 otherhostname`

-i is the interval to print results